# Generating (very) large non-repeating integer sequence without pre-shuffling

Tags: c, linux, random, hash, uniqueidentifier

## Background

I have a simple media client/server I've written, and I want to generate a non-obvious time value I send with each command from the client to the server. The timestamps will have a fair bit of data in them (nano-second resolution, even if it's not truly accurate, due to limitations of timer sampling in modern operating systems), etc.

What I'm trying to do (on Linux, in C), is to generate a one-to-one sequence of n-bit values (let's assume data is store in 128bit array-of-int elements for now) with no overlapping/colliding values. I would then take a pseudo-random 128bit value/number as a "salt", apply it to the timestamp, and then start sending off commands to the server, incrementing the pre-salted/pre-hashed value.

The reason the timestamp size is so large is because the timestamp may have to accommodate a very large duration of time.

---

## Question

**How could I accomplish such a sequence (non-colliding) with an initial salt value?** [The best approach that sounds along the lines of my goal is from this post, which notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8566077/1022889):

> If option 1 isn't "random" enough for you, use the CRC-32 hash of said
> global (32-bit) counter. There is a 1-to-1 mapping (bijection) between
> N-bit integers and their CRC-N so uniqueness will still be guaranteed.

However, I do not know:

- If that can (efficiently) be extended to 128-bit data.
- If some sort of addition-to/multiplication-by salt-value to provide the initial seed for the sequence would disrupt it or introduce collisions.

---

## Follow-up

I realize that I could use a 128bit random hash from `libssl` or something similar, but I want the remote server, using the same salt value, to be able to convert the hashed timestamps back into their true values.

Thank you.

Comment: As to the sequence: [Xorshift128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) is a fast 128-bit pseudo-random number generator with a period of 2¹²⁸-1. That is, given any nonzero 128-bit number, it yields another nonzero 128-bit number; the sequence goes through all 128-bit unsigned integers, except for zero. All n-bit PRNGs with period (2ⁿ)-1 have such features, not just linear congruential ones.

Comment: Future proofing your program till the heat death of the universe. I like it..

Comment: Yes you can extend CRC to 128 bits and you can find coefficients for that on Wikipedia's [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) page, but for what it achieves there are more efficient operations.  And yes you can add or multiply (if it's odd) your salt into any equivalent function without introducing collisions (mod 2**128).  So long as both functions are 1:1, the result of chaining them must also be 1:1.  I have such a function in mind, but I have to extend my search tool to 128-bit to find good parameters for it.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point. Sure, any old 128-bit LFSR will do, but I see no purpose for this other than wasting processor time. Why not just send it in the clear? If you need to hide it for some reason, then you'll need real encryption; the LFSR gives you no security at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a *linear congruential generator*. With the right parameters, it is guaranteed to produce non-repeating sequences [unique] sequences with a full period (i.e. no collisions).

This is what `random(3)` uses in `TYPE_0` mode. I adapted it for a full `unsigned int` range and the seed can be any `unsigned int` (See my sample code below).

I believe it can be extended to 64 or 128 bits. I'd have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator to see about the constraints on parameters to prevent collisions and good randomness.

Following the wiki page guidelines, you could produce one that can take *any* 128 bit value as the seed and will not repeat until all possible 128 bit numbers have been generated.

You may need to write a program to generate suitable parameter pairs and then test them for the "best" randomness. This would be a one time operation.

Once you've got them, just plug these parameters into your equation in your actual application.

---

Here's some code of mine that I had been playing with when I was looking for something similar:

```
// _prngstd -- get random number
static inline u32
_prngstd(prng_p prng)
{
    long rhs;
    u32 lhs;

    // NOTE: random is faster and has a _long_ period, but it _only_ produces
    // positive integers but jrand48 produces positive _and_ negative
#if 0
    rhs = jrand48(btc->btc_seed);
    lhs = rhs;
#endif

    // this has collisions
#if 0
    rhs = rand();
    PRNG_FLIP;
#endif

    // this has collisions because it defaults to TYPE_3
#if 0
    rhs = random();
    PRNG_FLIP;
#endif

    // this is random in TYPE_0 (linear congruential) mode
#if 0
    prng->prng_state = ((prng->prng_state * 1103515245) + 12345) & 0x7fffffff;
    rhs = prng->prng_state;
    PRNG_FLIP;
#endif

    // this is random in TYPE_0 (linear congruential) mode with the mask
    // removed to get full range numbers
    // this does _not_ produce overlaps
#if 1
    prng->prng_state = ((prng->prng_state * 1103515245) + 12345);
    rhs = prng->prng_state;
    lhs = rhs;
#endif

    return lhs;
}
```

Comment: Both answers were great (+1), but this is more in-line with what I was seeking. Thanks @all!

Comment: You're welcome! FYI, I had the above code at my fingertips because I was writing it for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472504/return-non-duplicate-random-values-from-a-very-large-range But, I got bogged down trying to write the one-time parameter generation program. It can use a _lot_ of CPU and a lot _more_ memory and it made my system swap like crazy. I needed to rearchitect. So, shelved temporarily.

Comment: You sent me a comment about your vim/checkpatch question and my suggestion, but then the question was deleted. Do you still need help [and will repost] or did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is encryption.  With a set of 128 bit values feed them into AES and get a different set of 128 bit values out.  Because encryption is reversible the outputs are *guaranteed* unique for unique inputs with a fixed key.

Encryption is a reversible one-to-one mapping of the input values to the output values, each set is a full permutation of the other.

Since you are presumably not repeating your inputs, then ECB mode is probably sufficient, unless you want a greater degree of security.  ECB mode is vulnerable if used repeatedly with identical inputs, which does not appear to be the case here.

For inputs shorter than 128 bits, then use a fixed padding method to make them the right length.  As long as the uniqueness of inputs is not affected, then padding can be reasonably flexible.  Zero padding, at either end (or at the beginning of internal fields) may well be sufficient.

I do not know your detailed requirements, so feel free to modify my advice.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere between linear congruential generators and encryption functions there are hashes that can convert linear counts into passable pseudorandom numbers.

If you happen to have 128-bit integer types handy (eg., `__int128` in GCC when building for a 64-bit target), or are willing to implement such long multiplies by hand, then you could extend on the construction used in [SplitMix64](http://xorshift.di.unimi.it/splitmix64.c).  I did a fairly superficial search and came up with the following parameters:

```
uint128_t mix(uint128_t x) {
    uint128_t m0 = (uint128_t)0xecfb1b9bc1f0564f << 64
                 | 0xc68dd22b9302d18d;
    uint128_t m1 = (uint128_t)0x4a4cf0348b717188 << 64
                 | 0xe2aead7d60f8a0df;
    x ^= x >> 59;
    x *= m0;
    x ^= x >> 60;
    x *= m1;
    x ^= x >> 84;
    return x;
}
```

and its inverse:

```
uint128_t unmix(uint128_t x) {
    uint128_t im0 = (uint128_t)0x367ce11aef44b547 << 64
                  | 0x424b0c012b51d945;
    uint128_t im1 = (uint128_t)0xef0323293e8f059d << 64
                  | 0x351690f213b31b1f;
    x ^= x >> 84;
    x *= im1;
    x ^= x >> 60 ^ x >> (2 * 60);
    x *= im0;
    x ^= x >> 59 ^ x >> (2 * 59);
    return x;
}
```

I'm not sure if you wanted a just a random sequence, or a way to obfuscate an arbitrary timestamp (since you said you wanted to decode the values they must be more interesting than a linear counter), but one derives from the other simply enough:

```
uint128_t encode(uint128_t time, uint128_t salt) {
    return mix((time + 1) * salt);
}

uint128_t generate(uint128_t salt) {
    static uint128_t t = 0;
    return encode(t++, salt);
}

static uint128_t inv(uint128_t d) {
    uint128_t i = d;

    while (i * d != 1) {
        i *= 2 - i * d;
    }
    return i;
}

uint128_t decode(uint128_t etime, uint128_t salt) {
    return unmix(etime) * inv(salt) - 1;
}
```

Note that `salt` chooses one of 2<sup>127</sup> sequences of non-repeating 128-bit values (we lose one bit because `salt` must be odd), but there are (2<sup>128</sup>)! possible sequences that could have been generated.  Elsewhere I'm looking at extending the parameterisation so that more of these sequences can be visited, but I started goofing around with the above method for increasing the randomness of the sequence to hide any problems where the parameters could pick not-so-random (but provably distinct) sequences.

Obviously `uint128_t` isn't a standard type, and so my answer is not C, but you can use either a bignumber library or a compiler extension to make the arithmetic work.  For clarity I relied on the compiler extension.  All the operations rely on C-like unsigned overflow behaviour (take the low-order bits of the arbitrary-precision result).